# How can I make my blogger post slider 100% width?

Tags: css, blogger

I have tried a lot to make it 100% width slider. But it gets chipped from the right side as you can see from my blog.  http://myideakart.blogspot.in/

This is the code that I pasted on my Html/javaScript widget

```html
<style>
/*crawlist.net slider CSS*/

.bx-wrapper {width:100%}
#slider {

    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
}



.slider-container { 
    background:#fff; 
    width:100%; 
    height:120px;
    z-index: 126;
    padding:0px 0px 43px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow:hidden; 
margin:0px 0px 45px 0px;
}

.newcon { width:100%; margin:0px 0px 43px 0px; overflow:hidden}


#slider img { 
    width:200px; 
    height:125px; 
    margin:0px; 
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;    
}

#slider li {
    width:210px
}
/*crawlist.net slider CSS*/
</style>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/35622252191/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#slider').bxSlider({
            ticker: true,

            tickerSpeed: 5000,
 
            tickerHover: true
          });
          });
</script>

        
<div class="newcon">
<!-- crawlist.net slider starts -->
<div class="slider-container">
<ul id="slider">   
<li><a href='http://myideakart.blogspot.in/2016/08/importance-of-social-media-marketing_10.html' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.typicalfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/B2B-Marketing.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href='http://myideakart.blogspot.in/2016/08/mark-zuckerberg-celebrated-skip-app.html' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="http://theideamarketing.com/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo-idea-marketing3-300x214.png"/></a></li>

<li><a href='place link' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="http://i-tul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/SEO_Blog_Tips_On_Going_Viral.jpg"/></a></li>

<li><a href='place link' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="http://btt.bloggertipstrick.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blogger-on-page-seo-tips.png"/></a></li>

<li><a href='place link' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="image link"/></a></li>

<li><a href='place link' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="image link"/></a></li>

<li><a href='place link' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="image link"/></a></li>

<li><a href='place link' title="place hover text" target="_blank"><img src="image link"/></a></li>
</ul>   
</div><!-- crawlist.net slider ends --></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems that causes this, first one is what Maciej suggested, add `width: 100%` to both `.bx-wrapper` and `.bx-window`, but in your HTML markup, you have a `style="width:840px"` attribute set on *both* elements. The problem with this is that the `style` attribute has higher priority than what's written in your CSS file (so it overwrites what you write in your CSS file), so you either have to remove that markup, or move your `width: 100%` declarations to the elements `style` attribute.

Comment: I think without adding `width:100%` is also working fine

Comment: @SathvikCheela Yes, `width: auto` (which is default) works fine if there are enough child elements that can fill up the client screen width, but this can become inconsistent on monitors that have, say, 4K resolution.

Comment: Point to be noted .. Thanks!!

Comment: here CSS cant locate .bx-wrapper and .bx-window because it generated from jquery. what fix for this?

Comment: Ah, you have to overwrite it *again* with JS then.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to .bx-window

```
width:for example 1200px;
```

or

```
width:100%;
```

So You have to make this code:

```
.bx-window{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: added and tried both .bx-wrapper {width:100%} .bx-window{width:100%;} both didn't helps here.

Comment: i tried it on the chrome and it's working :) try with width:100% !important;